# Is it possible to typedef a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

For example, in C I might write:

```c
typedef Foo (*MapCtx)(void * item, void * ctx);

// and now 'MapCtx' is a type
```

In Python 3, I have a function:

```py
map(item: Any, ctx: Optional[Any] = None, caster: Callable[[Any],Any]=lambda x: x)
```

Where the `caster` is more or less a callback handle intended to operate on the return value (to clean up the call if I need a type converter in there).

What I would like to do is define this as a type, and accept that type in a body of functions and class methods.

How would I do that in Python 3?

Comment: See [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable)

Comment: @Brian ah yeah, what I would like to do is assign the name 'MapCtx' to `Callable[[Any,  Context, Callable[[Any],Any], Tuple[Any,float]]`; but I don't see a clean way to do that.

Comment: Just do `MapCtx = Callable[[Any,  Context, Callable[[Any],Any], Tuple[Any,float]]`

Comment: @Chris. Your comment is much clearer than the question. Perhaps you could rephrase the question?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach ... :facepalm: lol

Comment: Happens to the best of us.

Comment: This would by a *type alias* in Python parlance.

Comment: By the way, with [PEP 613](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0613/), type aliases can be make more explicit with `TypeAlias`, e.g. `MapCtx: TypeAlias = Callable[...]`